# Show $(n_{i}+g_{i}-1)!\simeq(g_{i}-1)! g_{i}^{n_{i}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, factorial

I can' t comprehend why the the following is true: 
$$n_{i}<<g_{i}$$
$$(n_{i}+g_{i}-1)!\simeq(g_{i}-1)! g_{i}^{n_{i}}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$
(n+g-1)!=(n-1+g)!=(n-1+g)(n-2+g)\ldots(1+g)g(g-1)!
$$
and using $n << g$ approximate $(n-1+g)$ etc. by $g$:
$$
(n-1+g) \approx g\\
(n-2+g) \approx g\\
\vdots\\
(1+g) \approx g
$$
so
$$
(n+g-1)!=g\,g\,\ldots g\,g\,(g-1)!
$$
where there are $n$ terms in $g$, giving your result.

For a specific example if $g=1000$ and $n=10$ the approximations being made are
$$
1009\approx 1000\\
1008\approx 1000\\
\vdots \\
1001 \approx 1000
$$